# Adding commas between elements of a binary matrix in text file

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to read a binary / incidence matrix saved as a text file. The file currently looks like this:

[image: Original file contents]

When reading the file in R, it interprets the matrix as rows of numerals, which is not what I want. Hence, I hope to be able to add commas after each bit in the matrix and let R read it as a .csv file (which would interpret the data in the way I want).

Because I am not familiar with Unix and I do not have Microsoft Excel on my MacBook, I was wondering if someone could explain to me how I could perform the task described above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't include images of your input.  Paste the input into your answer and make it a codeblock (highlight it and press ctrl+k).  Also please provide a sample of what you would like your output to look like.

Comment: Ok! I'll be sure to do that next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed for this:

`sed -e 's/./,&/g' file`

On a mac you will have to use `-i[SUFFIX]` to modify the file in place so:

`sed -i.bak -e 's/./,&/g' file`

> Note: this will actually create a new file named [file].bak.  You can add `&& rm file.bak` to get rid of it in one line like:
>   `sed -i.bak -e 's/./,&/g' file && rm file.bak`

Comment: I used "sed -e 's/./,&/g' file.old > file.new" and obtained the required output. The "bak" command returned "": invalid command code -" as output. In any case, I now have the file I need, which R recognizes correctly. Thanks so much @Jesse_b!

Comment: It may not like that arrangement of arguments.  I've updated my answer but it may like `sed -i.bak -e 's/./,&/g2' file` better.  I'm not on my mac atm so unfortunately I can't check.

Comment: `sed 's/./,&/g2'` on a Mac fails.  [POSIX specs for `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) states that "If both g and [a number] are specified, the results are unspecified."  GNU `sed` info page says "Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the 'g' and NUMBER modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across 'sed' implementations.  For GNU 'sed', the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the NUMBERth, and then match and replace all matches from the NUMBERth on."

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it.  I guess that means the file would be created with leading commas though?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1
0000
0101
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS=","}{$1=$1;print}' file1
0,0,0,0
0,1,0,1
```